# Accessing Google Drive like server?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

Currently I'm working on an Android app that needs some centralized cloud storage location, for example a customer downloads my app and after entering their user ID the app will download their relevant information, ie name, user history, or any arbitrary small piece of information.

Since I've been working with the Google Drive API I thought I would simply set up account X to host all the customers information(none of this information is sensitive), probably in JSON format, and then whenever someone downloads my app it will connect to account X, and pull the relevant information from account X's Google Drive. The problem I have ran into is that on a device that has account X as a user account it works fine but when I try to connect on a device that doesn't have account X as a user account the app crashes.

**Is what I have described possible with Drive API? In order to connect to account X's Drive does the device in use have to have it as a user account, or do I have to make the relevant files public(in sharing options) for this to work?**

Answer (score 0):

**In order to connect to account X's Drive does the device in use have to have it as a user account?**

No.

What you need is an access token for account X. Once you have that, you can do Drive stuff against account X. The trick is how do you get that access token. Possibilities (not recommendations) include :-

- embed a refresh token for account X in your app
- embed a refresh token for account X in a server app, which your Android app invokes to fetch an access token
- use a service account

Comment: Its not a good idea to do this as your gdrive can get hacked. It will also fail if many simultaneous users use it.

Comment: feel free to post the specific scenarios that expose the risks you allude to

Answer (score 0):

Lots! You should never expose an access token from an account that is not owned by the user. That breaks the oauth protocol purpose. If the access token is not for the users drive then it should never leave the server side.
Unless you are using file specific scopes (this question does not) then the token will be good to delete the entire drive as well. No good.